# Microsoft Word Page Numbering Part-Section-Page

Tags: vba, ms-word, cpu-word, page-numbering

I have a long document with about 9 Parts and each part contains 2 - 5 sections. I want to have my page numbers read Part-Section-Page. For example, page 5 of section 4 in part 3 would have the page number 3-4-5.

Using this field code I can output this correct page number in my footer

```
{STYLEREF 1 \s}-{STYLEREF 2 \s}-{PAGE}
```

This works because the first field code outputs the current Part, signified by Header 1, the 2nd code outputs the section number signified by Header 2, and then last output is the page which I can control with section breaks.

BUT - This is no help with the Table of Contents! When the ToC is generated, Word only recognizes {PAGE} as the page number, and therefore I need to manually write the ToC.

Is there any way to make the page number actually be in the format x-y-x?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a non-programming question about using Word and, as such, is off-topic. If it were on-topic, it would still need revision. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This would be appropriate if asked in Word Answers http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word. (I know of no way to do all three in Word, two is possible.) See also John McGhie's warning about this style of numbering. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Numbering/ChapterNumber.htm

Comment: You might be able to finagle something with the \s Identifier switch of the TOC field code.